# Are SWX Data files modifiable by Client code?

Tags: actionscript, flash, swx

Data is stored in [SWX files](http://swxformat.org/), that is read natively by Flash Player as "objects".

Can the client request the server to update/**modify SWX** files, much like a MySQL database? How? SWX-PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to read SWX files on the server side. This would propably be quite hard to do, and not very practical.

You might consider storing your data in a database instead (for instance MySQL) and access it using for instance SWX-PHP services.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Technically, *data* isn't stored in SWX files; SWX files are SWF files that follow a certain specification. There are some good [definitions on the official web site](http://swxformat.org/documentation#71). In SWX-RPC, the SWX file is the implementation of the Remote Procedure Call protocol involved, and the protocol is usable via an SWX service wrapper, which shouldn't need to be modified by client code - if you need to modify it, why?

What's stored in the SWX file is the **actual code**, in the Flash Player native format, for example (in SWX-RPC) to handle the interaction with the underlying service gateway.

What you probably want to do *instead* of modifying SWX files is have a method for producing the SWX files you need for your interaction with the service gateway. Usually, a new SWX will only be necessary when the service interface changes. If you want SWX files some other reason than service interaction, feel free to comment.

For SWX-RPC via PHP, the SWX-PHP site has good [Getting Started examples](http://swxformat.org/82).

Comment: I believe you've got it all wrong. SWX is a file-format, which Flash Player understands natively. Maybe you mean to talk about "SWX RPC". See http://swxformat.org/documentation#71

Comment: No. I was talking specifically about SWX RPC, since that is used in most SWX service implementations. My statement "What's stored in the SWX file is the actual code" sums it up, doesn't it? Your question was kind of vague, so I assumed you were interested in the RPC part of SWX.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more clear about which assumptions I made, and why. Are you making any progress in your SWX endeavours?

Comment: I'd like to use SWX files for storing data. That can be changed by some server-side script or client-side web app, that way its an alternative to storing data in MySQL DBs with PHP for access.

Comment: Aha. I see. Yes, then you need server-side on-demand creation/modification of SWX files.